# Why I need app.CRUD if I can use db.query already

Tags: node.js, express, crud

sorry for the messy header.
That's what I want to ask:

Why I need to use app.get/post/update/etc... 
If inside this I have `db.query(q)...` that actually execute the query ?

Thanks :)

Relevant code:

```
app.post('/user',(req,res)=>{
    const {body} = req,
    {id,name,phone} = body,
    q = `INSERT INTO public.users(
        id, name, phone)
        VALUES (${id}, '${name}', '${phone}');`
       // debugger;
    db.query(q,(err,dbRes)=>{
            if(err)
            res.status(400).send(err)

            else
             res.send({
                 id,name,phone
             })
        })
})
```

Comment: Express is a framework that handles a lot of things for you. It provides a base/structure for you to start with. Sure, you could not use express and write your own way of creating a server using `http`, but that can be a big task depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, of course. The example code was worked well. 
But a lot of bad smell in your example.

1. It will expose your storage implementation，unable to effectively block the hack code.
2. If your service, not just a CRUD service, it combines the storage layer and logic layer. Will cause express and MongoDB(for example) coupling. Some days you want to use other storage, need to change a lot of code in the service layer.
3. It was not a good practice, with more and more code in the codebase, we will extract more bounded context. And last, to be the "app.CRUD" architecture.

If the service was simple, you can do anything if you want. But please do more consideration of software architecture in the important service.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is, it depends on what you design and accept.

If you are developing a fontend and you feel that it is not useful to use the backend, That means you can direct query. But if you need security (identity verification) before accessing the database, you should have a backend (your DRUD) and it's easy to work with dynamic queries. You should have it.

Comment: But I can make the same process in the server without it, am I wrong? I can make index.js that get the query/url, checking thimgs with JS and then execute the query.